# Insert into Table Valued Function return using dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a Table valued function, with some of the parameters nullable and others defining some of the table and column names the function will use. This means unfortunately a need for dynamic SQL. The query ran perfectly when I used in in SSMS, but trying to turn it into a function results in

> > Msg 443, Level 16, State 14, Procedure Events, Line 67 [Batch Start Line 0]
> >     Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function.

The function is meant to take the name of an event, which will form the event's datasource, and the key columns of the event tables, `"e.'+@eventType+'ID"` and `'e.'+@eventType+'Number'`

The function will have a report generated based on the return, and be joined to within another procedure to generate another report.

I've looked around but most examples and similar questions don't apply at all, usually looking to modify a table in the database, not a table variable, or otherwise not looking to insert into the return table variable. Is there any way to get around the restriction, either with temp tables or with inserting inside the dynamic sql?

```
IF (@childEvent IS NOT NULL) BEGIN
    SET @SQL = ' SELECT e.ProductID, e.ProductName, e.'+@eventType+'Number, e.Quantity - ISNULL(c.Quantity,0) AS Quantity '
         +' FROM {schema}.'+@eventType+'Table e '
         +' LEFT OUTER JOIN {schema}.'+@childEvent+'Table c '
         +' ON c.'+@eventType+'ID = e.'+@eventType+'ID '
END
INSERT INTO @Events 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@asOfDate Date',@asOfDate
```

Comment: Use a stored procedure, or a CLR table-valued function. You cannot execute dynamic SQL in a table-valued function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use dynamic SQL in a Table Valued Function.